# TortoiseGit trouble: git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit, github-for-windows

Here is a little bit background:

1. I run Win7
2. I have private git repo and installed Github for Windows
3. I didn't like the Github for Windows client (lack capabilities). I installed TortoiseGit for Windows (still keep Github for Windows)
4. I followed steps here exactly http://dancingmonkeysaccelerated.blogspot.com/2012/03/git-for-windows-with-tortoisegit-and.html
5. I can get log and commit local

[image]

6. Then I Push

[image]

7. However it gave error `git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)`

[image]

I read this thread:

[How to resolve "git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)" error on TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit)

And actually changed SSH key by running Puttygen THREE TIMES already. I also set Full Permission for Users in the folder. Nothing works!!

Here is what I see in Environment Path

> PATH=(others);C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_93e8418133eb85e81a81e5e19c272776524496c6\libexec\git-core;
>
> GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe
>
> SVN_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe
>
> SSH_ASKPASS=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe
>
> GIT_ASKPASS=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe

However: if I use `Github for Windows` it works fine.

Can someone point me to a direction to troubleshoot this TortoiseGit issue?

Comment: Does TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Environment variables shows you the environment variable `HOME` set? And if yes, is it to a path where you can see `%HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` files?

Comment: Could you check in your .git folder if there is an ´index_lock` file (or another file named lock? If so, delete it and try again.

Comment: @VonC I updated the question. Should I enter `%HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` exactly as-is? I don't see such folder `.ssh` anywhere. @Sgoettschekes There is no `index_lock` or any `lock` file. What's next?

Comment: `HOME` should point to a directory in which you see `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`: so the value you need to enter is *not* `%HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`, but a directory (like `%USERPROFILE%` or any other directory where Puttygen did generate those keys)

Comment: I guess I was a bit confused because there was no .pub file created by Puttygen. It was .ppk file. So I put it here `c:\TortoiseGit.ppk` and even when I have `c:\` in the path, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Any help please or should I use a different tool beside TortoiseGit?

Comment: Are you using TortoiseGit 1.8.0? Upgrade to TortoiseGit 1.8.1 and see if problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a better alternative for Windows: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/index.html

It's been working so far. But I still prefer TortoiseGit if I can get it to work.

Comment: I also tried TortoiseGit at some point (especially after using Tortoise-SVN for years), but I found it .. low quality and somewhat unintuitive. Currently, on Windows, I use, and I recommend everyone, the [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) package. It comes with: Git client, Cheetah, and even Git bash (with minimal Linux utils built for Win). Installs cleanly out-of-box. Git-Cheetach attaches to Explorer just like TortoiseXXX do, and is tailored to Git commands. Of course, that's just my preference, so I drop a comment, not answer, since the questions stays unsolved.

Comment: I just posted a new answer which should clearify differences between openssh and putty: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26100799/3906760

Answer (score 2):

## Generic answer

Every time `git.exe` is executed it returns an exit code (cf. [Does git return specific return error codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4917871/3906760)).

> An exit code of `0` indicates success.

In the StackOverflow post the exit code 128 is mentioned, which indicates an error:

> The `(exit code 128)` is some kind of "unexpected error" (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059956/3906760).
>   What it means is highly dependant on the git command executed and the output it issued. Therefore, there can't be a single easy and short answer on how to solve this.

The following post contains a specific answer which is related to the push case and at the end a more generic answer (If this doesn't help section).

---

## Answer for the case of the initial Stackoverflow post

The following answer is based on the fact, that `git.exe` was executed to run a push.

### Using TortoiseGit with SSH

Here one needs to differentiate between OpenSSH and PuTTY. ([See here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-network))

#### OpenSSH

In order to use OpenSSH you have to set `ssh.exe` as "SSH client" on TortoiseGit settings -> Network.
OpenSSH uses `%HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` files for their public/private keys by default, which must be created by OpenSSH `ssh-keygen` and not PuTTYGen (PuTTY keys have a different format, however, can also be converted using PuTTYGen).
If `%HOME%` is not set, TortoiseGit will set it automatically, if you manually set `%HOME%` please make sure it is valid (you might have to use slashes instead of backslashes).

This is recommended for people who already have their OpenSSH keys.

#### PuTTY

PuTTY, which is to be preferred on Windows, requires that public/private keys are created using PuTTYGen (which is shipped with TortoiseGit).
`TortoiseGitPlink.exe` needs to be selected as ssh client on TortoiseGit settings -> Network - that should be the default. However, there is no default place for the public/private keys and, thus, these *have to be configured*. There are (at least two ways to do that):

1. Configure your key to be the default key in PuTTY based applications.
   For this, open PuTTY (which is not shipped with TortoiseGit and has to be [downloaded](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) separately). Then go to the Connection-> SSH -> Auth configuration page and select your .ppk file as "Private key for authentication", go back to the "Session" configuration page, select "Default Settings" there and hit save. -> From now on PuTTY and PLink will use this key for authentication.
2. In order to make TortoiseGit load a private key for using with PuTTY one has to configure it.

   - *For an existing repository:* Choose a repository, open TortoiseGit settings -> Remote and select your remote repository configuration there (normally "origin"). Then select your private .ppk key and hit "Add new/Save".
   - *For a new repository* the key can be selected while cloning. *When pushing/pulling* make sure "Autoload putty key" is checked.

[More tips/tricks for using PuTTY.](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html)

---

## If this doesn't help

First of all we need to make sure that the right `git.exe` is called - normally that should be the case as TortoiseGit tries hard to find the correct `git.exe` on the system on first start-up. This can be easily done by going to the TortoiseGit settings -> General. There one should check whether "`git.exe` Path" points to the right folder of "Git for Windows" (in must point to the bin folder of the Git for Windows installation, not the cmd folder - but this should happen automatically) - if msysgit (the development version of "Git for Windows") is used, it is necessary that the `[MSYSGIT-INSTALL-PATH]\mingw\bin-folder` is on the path (i.e. entered in the Extern DLL Path textbox) in order to execute `git.exe` (otherwise required .dll-files) cannot be found. (See [TortoiseGit docs](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html))

Now click on "Check now" and check that the right version number appears next to the button (not no error message).
If this is working, `git.exe` should be configured correctly and work with https.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and I resolved it in the following way...

I have the NVIDIA "Tegra Android Development Pack" installed and it seems to also have a version of mysysgit.exe with it. TortoiseGit automatically found that installation location (instead of the standard git installation) and auto-populated it in the settings menu.

To correct this, go to: "Settings -> General" and there is a field for the path to mysysgit.exe. Make sure this is pointing to the correct installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made that commit (victim of did-not-exit-cleanly) from Git Bash. And tried the next commit from Tortoise, which worked!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't clone the git repo into my local folder,  bellow is the command that fixed it

git config --global http.sslverify false