# git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

i am getting this error.
Tried all the solution from [How to resolve "git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)" error on TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit)

I m using tortoise git & have git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: Without more information, I don't see how your question is different from the one you link to.

Comment: its quite late , but still a relevant question and may help others so thought of responding to it. So if you get this error, it may be because you have not logged into right github account. Incase you are not prompted to enter credentials, ensure that you remove passwords stored for git hub accounts in windows credential manager. Once you remove that ,when you try to push, there will be a prompt to enter your user name and password. You can enter your github credentials and then you can push your code to repo

Answer (score 2):

I guess you did not configured your email and name.
If not Configure them.

These are the steps to configure.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 128 means the file is not found.  Make sure TortoiseGit has been configured correctly to know which git.exe to run.

Try opening Git Bash and running git there, you might get a better error message.