# trying to use cookiecutter-django, getting errors and does not create anything

Tags: django, python-3.x, cookiecutter-django

trying to get a Django project started using cookiecutter-django and can't seem to get it to generate anything.
using Python 3.6, Django 2.0.5, cookiecutter 1.6.0 (then created a virtualenv and entered a new, blank directory)

so I enter this command:

```
    cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django
```

and get this error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python\python36\Scripts\cookiecutter.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in 
    <module>
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in 
    __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in 
    invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in 
    invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\cli.py", line 120, 
    in main
    password=os.environ.get('COOKIECUTTER_REPO_PASSWORD')
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\main.py", line 63, 
    in cookiecutter
    password=password
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\repository.py", line 
    103, in determine_repo_dir
    no_input=no_input,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\vcs.py", line 99, in 
    clone
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', 
    'https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django']' returned non-zero exit 
    status 128.
```

Comment: `git clone` returning 128 is usually a permissions issue. Do you have a GitHub account? You may also want to check your git config settings per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29429376/335583 if this is the first time using git.

Comment: thanks, it did seem to be some kind of Git configuration problem.  I couldn't figure out the CLI - todo for some other time.  I used the Github browser interface and was able to clone the repository.

Comment: ok, I still can't get cookiecutter-django to work.  I adjusted Git settings.  I am on Windows 10.  still getting the same traceback error.  seems like all the requirements are in order.  I just can't get cookiecutter to run cookiecutter-django.  cookiecutter itself seems to be pip installed properly.

Comment: For other people encountering this error message but they have their permissions set up correctly, this error message also happens when you mistype the GitHub URL. I accidentally did `cookiecutter gh:/pydanny/cookiecutter-django` (with an unnecessary slash before "pydanny") and got this same error message.

Answer (score 3):

OK - figured out how to get this to work.
used Github desktop

> from cookiecutter-django repository, right click
>
> open it Git Shell

this opens a Powershell window.

> CD to directory where project will be placed in.
> cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

and it works.
not sure exactly why this works when regular CMD and elevated CMD do not, but this was the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue with github due to the need to setup ssh keys. By the way I'm using ubuntu 12.

1. https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ - create a key first in your machine using the instructions in the link. Once you have your ssh key, proceed to step 2. (Step 2 is indicated in the first link as last step)
2. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account - add the generated ssh key to your github account.