# git-clean exits with non-zero status

Tags: git

I'm running `git clean -fdx` as a `sh` step in a Jenkins job, and the command sometimes exits with code 1 (after deleting a bunch of files+directories). What could be causing it?

This is on Linux, so it's not a matter of another process keeping a file open. There is no error output, unless Jenkins is hiding it.

Comment: Permission issue perhaps?

Comment: Can you run it manually from the same clone to make sure there is no output? Or redirect the output to a file in `/tmp` for later inspection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseGit-git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165953/tortoisegit-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-1)

Comment: @Mureinik All the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165953/tortoisegit-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-1 seem to be Windows-related

Answer (score 1):

Turns out another process was creating files after `git-clean` enumerated an ignored directory and before it deleted all the subdirectories, so `rmdir()` returned `ENOTEMPTY`.