# Git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Tags: gitlab, push, ssh-keys, tortoisegit

I can't push and I already tried all solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165953/tortoisegit-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-1) question. I'm using Windows10 and TortoiseGit.

I generated my SSH key with PuTTYgen and I already tried to replace the key in case my older was corrupted. When I try with git bash I got this error:

> $ git fetch -p Permission denied (public key).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

In TortoiseGit I get:

> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Comment: Seems as if the public key was not accepted by the remote server. Did you upload your matching public key to GitLab? - Compare the fingerprints or upload it again. make sure the right key is used for authentication.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded my key to GitLab. I have several keys now, do I have to delete all the others?

Answer (score 0):

For My case i did 3 steps to achieve the sucessful build.

1. revert all the local changes if any (or just keep a copy of it in case you need it for future use)
2. Do a git clean up, do a pull and check the logs for error
3. GO to the git bash option and  the error i was getting in log in above stem (i my case )
   as "**error: cannot lock ref and the branch details**", so in the git bash i ran the following command
   git update-ref -d 'Branch_name'

For example if the error was something like 
**

- ISSUE

**error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/EXMPLEISSUE/EXAMPLE-1011_DEMO_web_interface_DOES_NOT_GET_GIT_UPDATE':

Then i ran following command 
git update-ref -d 'refs/remotes/origin/EXMPLEISSUE/EXAMPLE-1011_DEMO_web_interface_DOES_NOT_GET_GIT_UPDATE'

We have to ensure all the error in logs to be solved similarly before getting a successful pull  by doing  git update-ref -d 'Branch_name' and finally  i can get the take the successful pull from git.