# How does echo $? work?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exit-code, automatic-variable

I am writing some PowerShell scripts to do some build automation. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917997/1977871) that **echo $?** returns true or false depending on previous statement. I just found that echo is alias for **Write-Output**. **Write-Host $?** also works. But I am still not clear how this **$?** works. Can someone kindly say some words bout this. Searching for echo $? on net did not give me much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find a complete Punctuation chart [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/2289-PSPunctuationWallChart_1_0_3.pdf). The answer (taken from the chart):

> Execution status of the last operation ($true or $false); contrast
>   with $LastExitCode that reports the exit code of the last
>   Windows-based program executed.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the chart, its succent. In the chart, at the bottom, I got this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), guess this is official documentation.

Comment: Yes, thats the official documentation. Your welcome.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39865555/45375) with more detailed information:

**tl;dr**

- Automatic variable **`$?`** (see [`Get-Help about_Automatic Variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)) contains a *Boolean* that reflects **whether *any non-terminating* error occurred** in the **most recent *statement***.

  - Since `$?` is set after *every* statement, you must either check it right after the statement of interest, or save it for later inspection.
  - See below for potentially counter-intuitive behavior.
- Automatic variable **`$LASTEXITCODE`** *complements* this by recording the ***specific exit code* of the most recently executed *external command-line utility*** (console application, such as `findstr`).

  - `$LASTEXITCODE` complements `$?` in that `$?` reflects only *abstract* success or failure of the external utility - exit code `0` is mapped to `$True`, any nonzero exit code to `$False` - whereas `$LASTEXITCODE` contains the actual exit code.
  - Since `$LASTEXITCODE` is only set for external command-line utilities, its value typically remains valid longer than `$?`, which is set after *every* statement.

---

There are many **subtleties** around how `$?` is set, and what, precisely, its value indicates:

- In PowerShell versions **prior to v7.2**, `$?` there is a **risk of false negatives for external command-line utilities**, i.e. it can report `$false` even when `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0`, namely when a `2>` redirection is used and actual stderr output is present - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726535/45375) for details.
- **`$?` only reflects the occurrence of *nonterminating* errors**, because (the much rarer) *terminating* errors by default terminate execution of the current command line / script, and to handle them you need to use `try / catch` (preferred) or `trap` (see the [`Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) and [`Get-Help about_Trap`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx)).

  - Conversely, you can opt to have non-terminating errors treated as terminating ones, using preference variable `$ErrorActionPreference` or common cmdlet parameter
    `-ErrorAction` (alias `-EA`) - see [`Get-Help about_Preference_Variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx) and [`Get-Help about_CommonParameters`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).
- Unless explicitly *ignored* (with the common `-ErrorAction Ignore` cmdlet parameter), **all non-terminating errors (and caught terminating errors) are collected in the automatic `$Error` collection**, in reverse chronological order; that is, element `$Error[0]` contains the most recent error.
- For commands to which *multiple* input objects were passed, **`$?` containing `$False` only tells you that processing of *at least one* input object failed**. In other words: an error could have occurred for *any subset* of the input objects, including *all of them*.

  - **To determine the exact error count and the offending input objects, you must examine the `$Error` collection.**
- With ***non-remoting indirect-execution* cmdlets** to which you pass a target command to execute - such as `Invoke-Expression`, `Start-Process`  and `Start-Job` and `Invoke-Command` *without* the `-ComputerName` parameter (which doesn't involve remoting - see below) - **`$?` only reflects whether the target command could be invoked *in principle*, irrespective of whether that command then reports errors or not.**

  - A simple example: `Invoke-Expression '1 / 0'` sets `$?` to `$True`(!), because `Invoke-Expression` was able to parse and *invoke* the expression, even though the expression itself then fails.
  - Again, inspecting the `$Error` collection tells you if and what errors the target command reported.
- With ***remoting* (invariably indirect-execution) cmdlets**, notably with `Invoke-Command` with the `-ComputerName` parameter (as is typical), but also with implicitly remoting cmdlets, `$?` *does* reflect whether the *target command* reported any errors.

  - A simple example (must be run from an *elevated* console and assumes that the local machine is already set up for remoting):
    `Invoke-Command -ComputerName . { 1 / 0 }`, because *remoting is involved*, indeed sets `$?` to `$False` to reflects the failure of target command `1 / 0`.
    <sup>Note that even though the local computer (`.`) is targeted, use of `-ComputerName` invariably uses remoting.</sup>
  - Note that, by design, remoting reports normally *terminating* errors that occur remotely as *non-terminating* ones, presumably so that a normally terminating error on one target machine doesn't abort processing on all others.

---

- Examples of commands that DO reflect errors in `$?`:

  ```
    # Invoking a non-existing cmdlet or utility directly.
    NoSuchCmd

    # Ditto, via call operator &.
    # Note, however, that using a *script block* with & behaves differently - see below.
    & 'NoSuchCmd'

    # Invoking a cmdlet with invalid parameter syntax.
    Get-ChildItem -NoSuchParameter

    # Invoking a cmdlet with parameter values that cause a (non-terminating) runtime error.
    Get-ChildItem NoSuchFile

    # Invoking an external utility that reports a nonzero exit code. 
    findstr -nosuchoptions
    # The specific exit code is recorded in $LASTEXITCODE, 
    # until the next external utility is called.

    # Runtime exceptions
    1 / 0

    # A cmdlet that uses remoting:
    # (Must be run from an elevated session, and the local machine must
    # be configured for remoting first - run `winrm quickconfig`).
    # Note that remoting would NOT be involved WITHOUT the -ComputerName parameter, 
    # in which case `$?` would only reflect whether the script block could be
    # _invoked_, irrespective of whether its command(s) then fail or not.
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName . { 1 / 0 }

    # A .NET method that throws an exception.
    # Note: Outside of a `try/catch` handler, this is a non-terminating error.
    # Inside a `try/catch` handler, .NET exceptions are treated as terminating
    # and trigger the `catch` block.
    [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted('>')
  ```
- Examples of commands that DO NOT reflect errors in `$?`:

  ```
    <#
      Non-remoting indirect execution cmdlets:

      $? reflects only whether the specified command could be 
      *invoked*, irrespective of whether the command itself then failed or not.

      In other words: $? is only $False if the specified command could not even be
      executed, such as due to invalid parameter syntax, an ill-formed target
      command, or a missing target executable. 

    #>

    # Invoking a command stored in a script block.
    & { 1 / 0 }

    # Invoking an expression stored in a string.
    Invoke-Expression '1 / 0'

    # Starting a background job.
    Start-Job { 1/ 0 }

    # The *non-remoting* form of Invoke-Command (WITHOUT -ComputerName).
    Invoke-Command { 1 / 0 }
  ```