# How can I redirect stdout and stderr without polluting PowerShell error output

Tags: powershell, error-handling, stderr

## Problem:

I am trying to run a command via PowerShell and capture its stdout and stderr *without* printing them on screen (command is incredibly noisy and pollutes the console).

I want to capture the stdout and stderr in a variable and then throw an exception if particular strings are found.

My logic seems to be working and I can make the cmdlet fail/pass when I expect it to, however the output does not match what I expect, instead of returning the error message that I am specifying I get what I believe is the stderr from the command instead?

## My code:

(Simplified for easier reading)
First cmdlet:

```
function Test-Validation
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Array]
        $ValidExitCodes = @(0),

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 1)]
        [bool]
        $FailOnWarning = $true
    )
    $Validation = . pdk validate 2>&1

    if ($LASTEXITCODE -notin $ValidExitCodes)
    {
        throw "Module validation has failed. Exit code: $($LASTEXITCODE)."
    }
    $Warnings = $Validation -match 'pdk \(WARNING\)'
    if (($Warnings) -and ($FailOnWarning -eq $true))
    {
        throw "Module validation contains warnings.`n$Warnings"
    }
    Write-Verbose "Module successfully passed validation"
}
```

Which is called by a second cmdlet:

```
function Test-Module
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    ()

    try
    {
      Test-Validation
    }
    catch
    {
      throw "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    try
    {
      Test-Unit
    }
    catch
    {
      throw "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

## Expected output

```
PS /opt/script/test/> Test-Module
Exception: /opt/script/test/Test-Module.ps1:13:9
Line |
  13 |          throw "$($_.Exception.Message)"
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Module validation has failed. Exit code: 1.
```

## Actual output

```
PS /opt/script/test/> Test-Module
Exception: /opt/script/test/Test-Module.ps1:13:9
Line |
  13 |          throw "$($_.Exception.Message)"
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | pdk (INFO): Using Ruby 2.5.8
```

As you can see it seems to be returning the output from the command I'm running (pdk) instead of the `"Module validation has failed. Exit code: $($LASTEXITCODE)."` message I am defining in the Test-Validation cmdlet.

Why am I not getting the error message I want and is there any way for me the achieve what I'm looking for?
Alongside any code suggestions I would very much appreciate any further readings around my issues to so I can better understand these things.

**N.B.**: This is being run by PoSh Core on MacOS

Comment: What is `pdk`, is it a native command or a PowerShell function? If it is native, then this Q&A may apply: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10666101/7571258

Comment: pdk is the 'Puppet Development Kit' it's an external binary, hence my dot calling of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$LastExitCode=0, but $?=False in PowerShell. Redirecting stderr to stdout gives NativeCommandError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101/lastexitcode-0-but-false-in-powershell-redirecting-stderr-to-stdout-gives)

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately not. It turns out it was a bug in PowerShell Core, see mklement0's response. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your symptom implies that `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is in effect at the time function
`Test-Validation` executes.
(Temporarily) set it to `'Continue'` to fix your problem - which in *future* versions will hopefully no longer required (see below).

The reason for the observed behavior is that, **in Windows PowerShell and up to PowerShell (Coe) *7.1*, using an error-stream *redirection* (`2>`) makes PowerShell route an *external program*'s stderr output *through PowerShell's error stream*** (see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)), and `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` therefore throws a script-terminating error once the first stderr line is received.

This behavior is unfortunate, because stderr output from external programs cannot be assumed to represent an *error* condition, given that external programs in effect use stderr, the standard error stream, for anything that *other than data*, which includes status information, for instance.

**PowerShell 7.2 and above change this behavior for the better**: stderr output is no longer routed through PowerShell's error stream, which means that:

- Stderr lines are (fortunately) no longer collected in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error).
- [Preference variable `$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) no longer has any impact on stderr output from external programs.
- The [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1), which indicates the *success status* of the most recently executed statement, is no longer incorrectly set to `$false` when the process exit code is `0` *and* there also happens to be stderr output  - though note that you can always infer success vs. failure of external programs via the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)