# Powershell return value after execute file.exe

Tags: c, powershell, exit-code

I created a simple test.c code:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    return -1;
}
```

Compiling with:
gcc -o test test.c

Later I executed it:
.\test.exe

Is it possible to see the return value in the terminal? not a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell reports the process exit code of the most recently executed console application in the [automatic **`$LASTEXITCODE`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

The related [automatic **`$?`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) is an *abstract* success indicator, reporting `$true` or `$false`, for *all* commands; in the case of console applications, a process exit code of `0` maps to `$true`, any other value to `$false`.

For reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946408/45375), it is better to use `$LASTEXITCODE` directly for console applications (`$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` to test for success) , because in PowerShell versions prior to 7.2, `$?` can yield false negatives.