# How to make git rebase fail, if merge conflicts appear

Tags: git

I'm currently writing trying to write a workflow, that rebases one branch onto another on each push. Now I want that action to fail, if any merge conflicts occur (as there is no way that my code would be able to resolve these).

Is there any flag or other way to make `git rebase` fail if merge conflicts appear? Can I reproduce this behaviour on another way?

How would I do this for `git merge`?

Comment: If there are merge conflicts the rebase will already fail.

Comment: In your script, check if the command exit code is `1`

Comment: Thanks for the input, didn't think the exit code would change if promted to resolve merge conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it's not obvious from the documentation most git commands fail with exit code 1.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917997/10816438) shows this behaviour for `git merge`, while [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471406/449449) assumes the same bahaviour for `git rebase`.